# Execute SQL Server Stored Procedure from VBScript that updates Linked server table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, vbscript, linked-server

I'm trying to run a VBScript which calls a stored procedure (SQL Server 2012) that Inserts records into a Linked Server Table.

The script returns the following error:

> The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file '\999999999\99999999\9999999\9999999.accdb'. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.".

*Nobody else is using the table.*

However, when I execute the stored procedure from Management Studio it works fine. I believe the problem is related to permissions. How do I grant a user explicit rights to Linked Servers?

---

*I apologize for not providing more detail to my question earlier, I made the mistake in thinking that there was a simple solution, with that said here are some more details:*

The key to this problem is: When I login as Windows Authenticated User on SSMS I'm able to run my Stored Procedure (Which connects to the Linked Server) without a problem. Couple of more technical points to add as I do more research (and finding this is not a simple problem):

1. The SQL Server is on Subnet ...5.X
2. The Access Database is on Subnet ...2.X
3. VBScript runs from a Job Processing Server on Subnet ...5.X
4. The Windows Authenticated Account on SQL Server has the Linked Server setup and can connect using the IP address and shared folder \192.168.2.X\Blah Blah Blah\thedatabase.accdb
5. If I login to SQL Server using SQL Server Authenticated User they cannot access the Linked Server (See error in original post)
6. If I attempt to run the VBScript from the Job Processing computer as the SQL Server Authenticated User or with a Trusted Connection I'm unable to access the Linked Server.

   - I've tried mapping a drive on the SQL Server computer for the SQL User (didnt work)
   - I've tried various combination of Login configurations on the Linked Server: Made without using security context, made using the login's current security context, made using the security context (admin username and password on other machince, SQL server admin username and password)
   - I've added the SQL User to the domain user group (But I only made them a standard user, need to research this one before making to many modifications)
   - I've added the SQL User as an Admin on the Access Database computer.

The key to my problem is: Why can the Windows Authenticated user connect to the MS Database via Linked Server and the SQL User cannot

Again apologies for not supplying this much detail upfront but I made the mistake of thinking this was a simple security problem.

Comment: This doesn't look like a problem with the SQL Server end of things. Access is complaining about write access to an Access (*.accdb) database; that's not a SQL Server error message.

Comment: @Matt but when I execute the same exact SP from Management Studio it runs fine. The only difference is I'm calling it from VBScript  which uses a different user login

Comment: Does it work fine if you log in as that different user in Management Studio and execute the SP? All I'm saying is that if it were a SQL Server permissions issue, I'd expect to see a SQL Server error message about permissions, not an Access error message about writing to a file.

Comment: Good point regarding the test I will run that now, but regarding the error that is the error received while debugging from Visual Studio.

Comment: @Matt when logged in as the specific user I get the following: OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "Blah Blah Blah" returned message "The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file '\\99999\99999\99999 1\99999.accdb'. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.".
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "Blah Blah Blah".

Comment: If I run Managment Studio as Windows Authenticated then it works fine. I could change the connection string for VBScript but I'd rather have a better understanding of how to secure properly.

Comment: Is it not down to how the linked server is configured? What authentication are you using? Do you set an explicit security context *(username and password)* or do you use security context mapping *(local user and remote user)* to impersonate?

Comment: @Lank Currently Using security context mapping

Comment: Is the "linked server" is actually an Access database? I'm a bit confused as to your setup.

Comment: So you've tested the query from SSMS using a security context of the `ADODB.Connection`?

Comment: @MattGibson The OP is calling a Linked Server that points to an Access database through SQL Server 2012.

Comment: That is correct the I'm linked to an Access Database

Comment: @Lank Yes currently run the SP from SSMS logged in using Windows Authenticated User. I'm now trying to automate the SP using VBscript

Comment: Personally I would use `Be made using this security context` then specify a `Remote login` and `With password` that matches a security context that has at least read/write access to the `mdb` file. That way the `ADODB.connection` just needs to connect with a security context that has rights to run the Linked Server the rest will be handled by SQL Server explicitly.

Comment: When you login to SSMS using a Windows Authenticated User is it the same user context you are testing the VBScript with *(I assume you call it via `wscript.exe` or `cscript.exe`)*?

Comment: @Lank I believe the answer is yes, I switched to Trusted Connection in my connection string and I'm calling the same SP. (Cscript.exe)

Comment: Originally I thought the problem was related to specific user in my connection string, so I switched to trusted but still have the same problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102458/discussion-between-lankymart-and-jrobinson6274).